# Long black screen during boot on Ubuntu 18

Tags: boot, 18.04, amd-graphics

Up until now, I used Ubuntu 16 and everything worked fine.
But then I did a clean install of Ubuntu 18 and now I am faced with a quite annoying problem.

Every time I turn on my computer, then during Ubuntu boot process the screen goes black, the computer does nothing, this continues 2 minutes, and then the PC continues to boot normally.

How can I fix this issue? I am using an HD5850 GPU with ubuntu drivers and have no extra hardware installed.

Here is the blame log

```
  1min 2.622s apt-daily-upgrade.service
         35.903s plymouth-quit-wait.service
         26.544s apt-daily.service
         15.870s dev-mapper-main\x2dsystem.device
         14.741s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
         13.610s dev-loop13.device
         13.574s dev-loop7.device
         13.504s dev-loop0.device
         13.493s dev-loop4.device
         13.480s dev-loop1.device
         13.448s dev-loop2.device
         13.384s dev-loop3.device
         13.357s dev-loop5.device
         13.351s dev-loop6.device
         13.334s dev-loop8.device
         13.320s dev-loop9.device
         13.286s dev-loop11.device
         13.257s dev-loop12.device
         13.206s dev-loop10.device
         12.549s snapd.service
         12.420s phpsessionclean.service
         12.400s plymouth-start.service
         10.951s networkd-dispatcher.service
lines 1-23...skipping...
     1min 2.622s apt-daily-upgrade.service
         35.903s plymouth-quit-wait.service
         26.544s apt-daily.service
         15.870s dev-mapper-main\x2dsystem.device
         14.741s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
         13.610s dev-loop13.device
         13.574s dev-loop7.device
         13.504s dev-loop0.device
         13.493s dev-loop4.device
         13.480s dev-loop1.device
         13.448s dev-loop2.device
         13.384s dev-loop3.device
         13.357s dev-loop5.device
         13.351s dev-loop6.device
         13.334s dev-loop8.device
         13.320s dev-loop9.device
         13.286s dev-loop11.device
         13.257s dev-loop12.device
         13.206s dev-loop10.device
         12.549s snapd.service
         12.420s phpsessionclean.service
         12.400s plymouth-start.service
         10.951s networkd-dispatcher.service
```

Answer (score 0):

I may have found an answer, someone else asked a similar question with my experience of upgrading to 18 AND doing a fresh install.

I did this and it completely solved my blank screen problem that took minutes. Hopefully it solves it for you?

[Boot hangs for 30 seconds at "Begin: Running /scripts/local-premount"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034359/boot-hangs-for-30-seconds-at-begin-running-scripts-local-premount)