# Boot hangs for 30 seconds at "Begin: Running /scripts/local-premount"

Tags: boot, 18.04

After upgrade from Ubuntu 17.10 to 18.04 the bootprocess takes 30s longer than before.

it stops for 30 seconds at the step

> Begin: Running /scripts/local-premount

Then it continues.

At first it continued one step further to

> scanning for btrfs file systems

so I [uninstalled btrfs support](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/78535/how-to-get-rid-of-the-scanning-for-btrfs-file-systems-at-start-up), but that didn't help with the problem.

I see no notice of that step neither in `dmesg` nor in `var/log/boot.log`

How can I debug this problem? Can I enable additional logging?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Try the following:

- open `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume`
- replace `RESUME=UUID=xxx` with `RESUME=none`
- issue `sudo update-initramfs -u`
- reboot your system

(create the file if it does not exist and just add `RESUME=none` in it)

The file should contain the UUID of your swap partition, you can check this with `sudo blkid | grep swap`.

I found the following [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1763611) on launchpad which is supposed to be Lubuntu specific but the commands above also resolved the same issue on my Xubuntu installation.

See comments [#27](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1763611/comments/27) and [#28](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1763611/comments/28).

This file seems to be related to hibernate/suspend, I can confirm `suspend` still works on my system after the changes.

Comment: thanks, that worked! I also posted your solution here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/443272/20661

Comment: I removed my swap parition manually before upgrading, but I guess it was still remembered somewhere as the RESUME field was set to the old UUID. Setting it to none shaved at least 30s from my bootup time! Top!

Comment: For me the issue was that I didn't have a swap partition at all (no idea how that happened). I fixed my problem by creating a swap partition and adding it to the file as described in this answer.

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean with "The file should contain the UUID...". I have two TYPE="swap" UUID, the _real_ (/dev/sda6) and the mapped (/dev/mapper/cryptswap1). Maybe this happen if you don't have swap partition OR its encrypted. Anyway, I left the `=none` and everything works fine now.

Comment: Do not add a backup or save a renamed copy of that file in the same directory. I did that, and it still tried using resume=UUID when I ran initramfs. Removing the copy fixed it, so I'm assuming it scans all files in that directory.

Comment: Just want to note that deleting `RESUME=UUID=xxx` also seems to fix the problem (or deleting the entire file if the only thing it contains is `RESUME=UUID=xxx`). Also FYI the RESUME variable is discussed in the initramfs-tools man page. https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/initramfs-tools.8.html

Comment: The problem with this method is that when the "update-initramfs-tools -u" is executed, in my case, it output the following: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-56-generic.
This implies that the next time the kernel gets updated, which should also change the version number in initrd.img, then this entire procedure has to be re-done.
If what I said is true, then would there be any other way of overcoming the problem of 30s delay?

Comment: For me adding an existing UUID to that file also worked, as I previously had deleted my SWAP partition, making the stored UUID invalid.

Answer (score 11):

In my case, the hang at `Running /scripts/local-premount` was caused by grub configs. So the workaround that I found is updating `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` config to `noresume`.
Type this in your terminal:

```
sudoedit /etc/default/grub
```

Find `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` and change its value to `noresume`.

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="noresume"
```

If you don't find that line, you can add it at the end of file. You can update the default one, too:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="noresume"
```

For me, I did both. Save the configs. Then update the grub:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Reboot the computer. It should now be faster.
Btw, you can combine `noresume` with `quite` and `splash`, if you use splash boot.

See also related answers on [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/1031667) and [superuser](https://superuser.com/a/48811), as well as documentation about this parameter on [linuxtopia](https://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/linux_kernel/kernel_configuration/re33.html)

Comment: This will prevent suspend-to-disk and resume. (Can also be done by uninstalling ...resume... probably.) But thanks for the hint, I disabled resume from command prompt, and could boot once to fix my problems.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with all the install of Ubuntu.

I'm using LVM with swap on a LV.

On a desktop `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume` is referring to an UUID which avoid the possibility to hibernate.

On a Server `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume` does not exists after install and introduce delay at boot and/or lvmetad error.

```
sudo su -c 'echo RESUME=/dev/mapper/the_swap_LV_name > /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume' 
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

[https://launchpad.net/bugs/1768230](https://launchpad.net/bugs/https://launchpad.net/bugs/1768230)

No more delay at boot or lvmetad error.

Kind Regards