# Slow boot since dist-upgrade to 18-04

Tags: upgrade, 18.04, boot-time

My laptop has become slower in boot time since the upgrade to Bionic Beaver.

Most of the time (about 30 seconds) is lost here, according to dmesg:

```
[ 3.376986] input: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad as /devices/platform/i8042/serio2/input/input10
[ 3.804388] [drm] RC6 on
[35.544677] EXT4-fs (nvme0n1p1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[35.625669] ip_tables: (C) 2000-2006 Netfilter Core Team
```

With a nvme SSD, newly installed, it booted in 20 seconds. How can I find out what process uses the lost time? 
What does the time in brackets say, the startup time or time finished?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem already with this:
[Boot hangs for 30 seconds at "Begin: Running /scripts/local-premount"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034359/boot-hangs-for-30-seconds-at-begin-running-scripts-local-premount)

Boot time is back at 18.62 seconds