# Ubuntu: Boot hangs for 30 seconds at "Begin: Running /scripts/local-premount"

Tags: 20.04

[Boot hangs for 30 seconds at "Begin: Running /scripts/local-premount"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034359/boot-hangs-for-30-seconds-at-begin-running-scripts-local-premount)

```
Try the following:

open /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume
replace RESUME=UUID=xxx with RESUME=none
issue sudo update-initramfs -u
reboot your system
```

but in mine

```
android@inspi:/etc$ cat /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume
cat: /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume: No such file or directory
```

**/etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf**

```
android@inspi:/etc$ cat /etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf 
#
# initramfs.conf
# Configuration file for mkinitramfs(8). See initramfs.conf(5).
#
# Note that configuration options from this file can be overridden
# by config files in the /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d directory.

#
# MODULES: [ most | netboot | dep | list ]
#
# most - Add most filesystem and all harddrive drivers.
#
# dep - Try and guess which modules to load.
#
# netboot - Add the base modules, network modules, but skip block devices.
#
# list - Only include modules from the 'additional modules' list
#

MODULES=most

#
# BUSYBOX: [ y | n | auto ]
#
# Use busybox shell and utilities.  If set to n, klibc utilities will be used.
# If set to auto (or unset), busybox will be used if installed and klibc will
# be used otherwise.
#

BUSYBOX=auto

#
# COMPCACHE_SIZE: [ "x K" | "x M" | "x G" | "x %" ]
#
# Amount of RAM to use for RAM-based compressed swap space.
#
# An empty value - compcache isn't used, or added to the initramfs at all.
# An integer and K (e.g. 65536 K) - use a number of kilobytes.
# An integer and M (e.g. 256 M) - use a number of megabytes.
# An integer and G (e.g. 1 G) - use a number of gigabytes.
# An integer and % (e.g. 50 %) - use a percentage of the amount of RAM.
#
# You can optionally install the compcache package to configure this setting
# via debconf and have userspace scripts to load and unload compcache.
#

COMPCACHE_SIZE=""

#
# COMPRESS: [ gzip | bzip2 | lz4 | lzma | lzop | xz ]
#

COMPRESS=lz4

#
# NFS Section of the config.
#

#
# DEVICE: ...
#
# Specify a specific network interface, like eth0
# Overridden by optional ip= or BOOTIF= bootarg
#

DEVICE=

#
# NFSROOT: [ auto | HOST:MOUNT ]
#

NFSROOT=auto

#
# RUNSIZE: ...
#
# The size of the /run tmpfs mount point, like 256M or 10%
# Overridden by optional initramfs.runsize= bootarg
#

RUNSIZE=10%
```

Comment: Did you try creating the file? in `/etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf` says `# Note that configuration options from this file can be overridden
# by config files in the /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d directory.`

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo gedit /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume
```

> RESUME=UUID=18469c87-14e0-4dca-8cb6-591d41298d1e

```
android@inspi:~$ sudo update-initramfs -u -k all
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-28-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-26-generic
android@inspi:~$
```

> android@inspi:~$ sudo lsblk -f NAME   FSTYPE LABEL       UUID
>   FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINT sda
>   ├─sda1 vfat               ACC7-9A1B                             140.1M
>   52% /boot/efi ├─sda2 swap
>   18469c87-14e0-4dca-8cb6-591d41298d1e                [SWAP] ├─sda3 ext4
>   3c1e55bc-8bdc-4742-912d-337da429b83f   96.1G     5% / ├─sda4
>   ├─sda5 ntfs               80D47B63D47B59FC
>   └─sda6 ntfs   router_data 4416017316016770                      111.4G
>   60% /home/android/routerbin sr0
>   android@inspi:~$